# Url Image in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I using the LJWebImage sample project, Which,I found from github on the following link https://github.com/likumb/LJWebImage. Project,similar to SDWebImage.I am successfully imported the sample project into my project.I am using collectionView to populating the image from plist which contain number of url links.I am trying pass the collectionView selected cellimage to my imageView but no luck so for.please someone point me the direction.my partial collectionView code below.

Thanks in Advance.

```
let apps: NSArray = AppInfo.appInfo()

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

          collectionView!.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - CollectionView data source


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return apps.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Cell

    cell.app = apps[indexPath.row] as? AppInfo

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "apps", ofType: "plist"), 
       let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = image
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code of prepare for segue or navigation from 1st vc to second vc.

Comment: @Nirav D   collectionView and  imageView  in the same viewController.i am not using segue at all..thanks

Comment: Then what is the meaning to access plist instead of apps Array.

Comment: @Nirav D . I was trying to use apps array.but, I am not sure how to use it. can you elaborate . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the corresponding app object from the data source array using the indexPath.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let app = apps[indexPath.row] as? AppInfo else { return }
    guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: app.filePath) else { return }

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image
}
```

Or you could retrieve the cell using the indexPath and get the image from it's imageView.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Cell else { return }

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = cell.imageView.image
}
```